# How does the relative acidity of 2,3-dinitrophenol compare to that of 2,4-dinitrophenol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance, phenols, inductive-effect

I am assuming that the -I inductive effect in 2,3-dinitrophenol is stronger than in 2,4-dinitrophenol since it operates through less bonds, therefore on inductive grounds it should have a lower $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$?

However it's unclear to me whether there are any differences in  π-resonance effects. Any help?

Comment: Can you draw resonance structures for the conjugate base?

Comment: @orthocresol I got 3 resonance forms for the conjugate bases of each. Is this correct?

Comment: You seems to forgot to include nitro groups. Try again and see.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Are 6 resonance structures for the ortho and para nitro substituents, but only 5 for the ortho meta substituents since 3-nitro group cannot delocalize the charge?

Comment: Sounds like you've got it correctly. Then, which conjugate base is the relatively more stable?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne the conjugate base of 2,4-nitrophenol would be more stable and therefore it would be more acidic. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: You got it! :-)